# Payment domain intent is showing internet result instead of intent UI or intent confirmation using Sirikit

Tags: xcode, swift3, ios10, sirikit, xcode8-beta3

I am using SendPayment intent using Sirikit with my payment domain app. 
Once I say "Send 10$ to William using payments app", it goes to Intent handler but it shows internet results rather than asking for the confirmation and showing default intent UI.
It was working last week, but it suddenly stopped working. 
Anybody else facing this issue?
I checked the other domain like "SendMessage" is working.

Any leads on this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have found that you need to add a paymentRecord to the INSendPaymentIntentResponse, before returning it from the confirm and handle methods in the Payment Intent Handler.  Give this a shot and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Adding a paymentRecord does indeed get rid of the error. THANK YOU !!!!

Comment: As I have only to hardcode it to show it in a demo is grand, what you suggest about manually adding a paymentRecord seems to work (thanks!), but I wouldn't mark it as the valid solution for this post, that's not the way it's supposed to be. Also, for the handle part, it redirects to the app when before it was handling the UI as well

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing the same issue.

SendPayment intent was working late last week. No code changes and when I tested it today it just pulls up web search results instead of showing the payment confirmation.

What is weird is that if you trace it, it is properly calling the following 2 methods:

```
resolvePayeeForSendPayment: withCompletion:
resolveCurrencyAmountForSendPayment: withCompletion:
```

But confirmSendPayment: completion: is never called.

Also reported by a user in this thread on Apple Dev Forums (post #3)
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/158939#158939

Upgrading to Beta 4 on the phone didn't help (same behavior).
Installing Xcode Beta 4, recompiling, and redeploying didn't help (same behavior).